# Catch input id on switch change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to catch the input id with similar to event.target.id when clicking on the switch, some thing like  $('input[name="shelf-" + event.target.id]') ?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="shelf-1" id="1" data-size="mini">
<input type="checkbox" name="shelf-2" id="2" data-size="mini">
<input type="checkbox" name="shelf-3" id="3" data-size="mini">
<input type="checkbox" name="shelf-4" id="4" data-size="mini">

$('input[name="shelf-1"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state)
{
      if (state == true) 
       {
         alert('ON')
         var id;
         var state;
         id = ($(this).attr('id'));
         state = "ON"
         myFunction(id,state)
       }
       else
       {
         alert('OFF')
         var id;
         var state;
         id = ($(this).attr('id'));
         state = "OFF"
         myFunction(id,state)
       }
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to apply same event handler to all inputs?

Comment: I want to be able to use the same code for all switches.

Comment: just checkt your selector to use a starts with path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of options here,

- Use jQuery `:checkbox` selector like `$('input:checkbox').on()`
- Use a starts with selector like `$('input[name^="shelf"]').on()`
- Add a class name and use it like `$('input.myclassname').on()`

and so on...